# How can I add data "letterID" passed from a different screen to my list?

Tags: list, flutter, parameter-passing

I am trying to make a GridView of images and the images asset path changes depends on the data passed from the previous screen which is "letterID" as String. For example if the user chooses letter "A" which is "letterID = L1" or if the user chooses the letter "B", "letterID" will be "L2". But I keep getting the following error:

Error: Can't access 'this' in a field initializer to read 'letterID'.
'assets/letters/letter-words/' + letterID + 'W1.png',

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class letterWordsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  String letterID;

  List<Widget> letterWordsImages;

  letterWordsScreen(String letterID) {
    this.letterID = letterID;
  }

  @override
  State<letterWordsScreen> createState() => _letterWordsScreenState();
}

class _letterWordsScreenState extends State<letterWordsScreen> {
  String letterID;

  letterWordsScreen(String letterID) {
    this.letterID = letterID;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {}

  List<String> letterWordsImages = [
    'assets/letters/letter-words/' + letterID + 'W1.png',
    'assets/letters/letter-words/' + letterID + 'W2.png',
    'assets/letters/letter-words/' + letterID + 'W3.png',
    'assets/letters/letter-words/' + letterID + 'W4.png',
  ];
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'Letter Words Screen',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: GridView.builder(
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2, crossAxisSpacing: 5, mainAxisSpacing: 5),
            itemCount: letterWordsImages.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  print('I have been touched!');
                  popUpImage(letterWordsImages[index]);
                },

                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    image: AssetImage(letterWordsImages[index]),
                  )),
                ),
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class letterWordsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      String letterID;
    
      
    
      letterWordsScreen(String letterID) {
        this.letterID = letterID;
      }
    
      @override
      State<letterWordsScreen> createState() => _letterWordsScreenState();
    }
    
    class _letterWordsScreenState extends State<letterWordsScreen> {
      String letterID;
    
     
    
      @override
      void initState() {     
    letterID = widget.letterID;
       }
    
      List<String> letterWordsImages = [
        'assets/letters/letter-words/' + letterID + 'W1.png',
        'assets/letters/letter-words/' + letterID + 'W2.png',
        'assets/letters/letter-words/' + letterID + 'W3.png',
        'assets/letters/letter-words/' + letterID + 'W4.png',
      ];
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
          appBar: AppBar(
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0,
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text(
              'Letter Words Screen',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2, crossAxisSpacing: 5, mainAxisSpacing: 5),
                itemCount: letterWordsImages.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      print('I have been touched!');
                      popUpImage(letterWordsImages[index]);
                    },
    
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        image: AssetImage(letterWordsImages[index]),
                      )),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          ),
        );
      }
```

Comment: I have tried your method but sadly it did not work, I still get an error with the "letterID" in the List.